# Django 3.0 Reverse for slug based name in urls.py cannot be called in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am using Django 3.0 to create a basic website and I am obviously still new. My issue is that I am not able to dynamically call the DetailView using the {% url 'my_page' %} format.

I set up an About Us section for which the slug is about-us, and my ulrs.py has name="<-slug:slug>" (I figured this isn't right), and get *NoReverseMatch at /, Reverse for 'about-us' not found. 'about-us' is not a valid view function or pattern name.*

I have a Section model set up as follows in **models.py**:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Section(models.Model):
    section_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    section_bg = models.ImageField(upload_to='section-bg')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.section_title)
        super(Section, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_title
```

The relevant **views.py** view:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from . import models

class SectionView(DetailView):
    template_name = "home/section.html"
    model = models.Section

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

And finally, in **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(r'home/<slug:slug>/', views.SectionView.as_view(), name='<slug:slug>'),
    ...
]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change url name to something readable and meaningful (ex. `name=section_detail`) and to link to detail page use `{% url 'section_detail' slug=object.slug %}`.